# Getting InAppBillingPurchaseException when try to purchase a product

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

To Update my App to use InApp-Purchase in Xamarin Form, I'm using InAppBilling Plugin https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/. I setted up correctly the sandbox account on my phone and I can tell you that is correct as using a dummy app everything just works fine.
The problem I have is when I'm trying to get a product or purchase a product that I created on App Store Connect:

1- When I'm trying to get product information
`var result = await billing.GetProductInfoAsync(ItemType.Subscription, new string[] { Product });`
the result is always empty

2- When I'm trying to purchase a product I got this exception: Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions.InAppBillingPurchaseException: Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Is it working in android? because I got the result is null in android any idea about that.

Comment: See same issue here : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/243, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/217